# Choose install directory for .NET installers like GitHub for Windows, SourceTree for Windows?

Tags: .net, windows, installation, clickonce

Is it possible to specify a install path for modern .NET packed softwares like

- [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/)
- [SourceTree for Windows](http://sourcetreeapp.com/windows/)

As a developer I hate installers force install into system partition. Perhaps some launch parameters in MSI or some xml files editing will do the magic?

If it's hard coded path (%localappdata%\local\apps), where's the MSDN reference for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For applications that use Microsoft's ClickOnce deployment (like GitHub), you can't specify the installation folder. These applications get installed under the user's profile and are isolated, where they can't mess with anything in Program Files or pretty much anywhere on the computer except for MyDocuments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running [msiexec](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html) ([MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)) from the command line and specifying the value of the [TARGETDIR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) public property:

```
msiexec /i "path to my msi" TARGETDIR="install to this folder"
```

Note that depending on the author of the MSI this may not work - not everybody follows the standards.